# TinyMCE problem on IE9

Tags: tinymce, internet-explorer-9

I am using old version of TinyMCE and it has lots of changes. Its working fine on IE6,7,8, FF, Chrome but not IE9. When I click on any button, nothing happens. I currently I could not update because I have lots of changes made to the current one. When I click on a button or on the content, I got this message:

**SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'parentElement'**

Can anybody tell me what cause the error and how can I get it solved without upgrading the editor?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The new tinymce version works fine with IE9. Older versions of tinymce don't! Eighter you work with older Browsers or you will have to update your tinymce. 
Where have you made changes to? Best practice is to implement changes and additional functionality using an own tinymce plugin. This makes it easier to update to more recent versions.

Comment: Is there any documentation anywhere that states that updating tinymce should fix this issue? I am getting this error and duplicate and am trying to find something definite to point to from MS to TinyMCE saying that this will definitely address the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Update your tinyMCE and get the **tiny_mce_gzip.js** and **tiny_mce_gzip.php** from the "Compressor 2.0.4 PHP" package downloadable from the tinyMCE's website.